# Azure B2C Registration Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure B2C authentication in my mvc application. I have a "SignIn/Register" and "Edit Profile" policy created.

When a user want to register he need to click the "Sign In"-button and choose at the end of the page:

> Don't have an account? Sign up now

Is there any way for a direct "Register"-Button on my page? I did not find any tutorial for registration only for the "Sign in".

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate sign-up policy. Select Azure AD B2C from the services list in the Azure portal, click on 'Sign-up policies', add the fields that are required as part of the sign-up experience, and click 'create'. You should open the just-created policy in the portal, add the Reply URL/Redirect URI, and click 'Run Now' to ensure it functions as expected. There is a walkthrough with images here: [Create a sign-up policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-policy)

The only actual difference between requests that invoke a sign-up policy and requests that invoke a sign-in policy is the policy name that's used in the "p" query string parameter (&p=b2c_1_siup for sign-up, &p=b2c_1_siin for sign-in).

You can also customise the authentication UI either by hand or using the helper tool, documented at: [Customize the Azure AD B2C UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-policy)

Comment: What lines of code do i need in my MVC Controller for the SignUp Policies? The Sign-In looks like: "HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();"

Comment: Finally got it with that Policy and this lines of code: 
           if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Startup.RegistrationPolicyId);

                var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" };
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);
                return;
            }

Comment: Sorry all i did not get it how to format the code here :-(

Comment: @DarkWing89 don't put code in comments. Either in question or answer, select the code snippet & press ctrl+k to format..